# chrome cache persisting old site

Tags: google-chrome, caching

Going live with a new site today I ran into a strange issue on Chrome:

We changed the DNS to point to a new server with a new site, and Chrome seemed to have cached the old index.html file, but none of the srcs or includes.. so it rendered the text from the old index.html but generated 404s on all the css and imgs.. and displayed an ugly mess.

I hacked a workaround: locating a js file the old index file was looking for I injected a new js file that redirected the call to "index.html" instead of "/" and that resolved it, but with an ugly temporary flash of the hideous mess that was the cached index file.

Everything I Googled told me how to flush the cache, but I'm not concerned how MY browser reads the site, I'm concerned with how others browsers read the site.  Tried putting a no-cache tag in to no avail.. read later that chrome ignores that tag...

Anyone encounter this before and have a better solution??

**UPDATE:** In case anyone else stumbles into a similar situation.  Looks like the old site had a cache setting in the web.config.  Thanks to Nitin for suggesting the logs. Examining network traffic in Dev tools I could see the cached retrieve, and more importantly the cache control response header that led me to start examining files on old site.

Lesson learned: Look for and remove cache settings before going live with a new site.

Comment: clear your history from settings >history or you can add cache clear extension.

Comment: thanks, but as I said.. I'm not concerned with how my browser reacts, I'm concerned with how my site visitors browser react.. I cant tell them to clear their history

Comment: your right Steve, but there is no issue with the chrome your server should be able to respond with updated  http information.

Comment: the old server was offline.. what chrome was displaying no longer existed on the web anywhere.. other browsers,if they hiccuped, only required a refresh.  Chrome, with a reboot and a refresh, now 12 hours later is still tying to display a file that only exists in its cache.  Perhaps it is an IIS issue.. not telling chrome the file is new cuz as far as the new server's IIS is concerned its the only index file ever.. dunno..

Comment: did you tried with other browsers (IE or firefox) and  check the both server as well as browser console logs (network logs > check request and response) it will help you to debug your issue.